# What's the best way to drive same JUnit Class with different RemoteWebDrivers?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, webdriver

At the time I use Class Parameterized to drive the same tests in different Browsers. What I don't like about it is, that the tests don't run in parallel.

I also tried [this](http://www.scribd.com/barsan_dan/d/66306687-Running-SoapUI-Parameterized-JUnit-Tests-in-Parallel) but it didn't work for me but I admit that I didn't really understood what I was doing.

Isn't there a better way to do it?

Is there a way with Maven/Surefire to get this done?

Is anyone experienced in achieving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run tests in parallel, JUnit might not be the perfect tool. Try [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) instead. It already knows how to run tests in parallel, so you don't have to worry about this.

To configure the tests for different browsers, follow this approach:

```
public abstract BaseBrowserTests {
     public abstract WebDriver getDriver();

     ... common tests...
}

public void ChromeTests {
     ... implement getDriver() to connect to Chrome ...

     ... you can add specific Chrome tests here ...
}
```

Comment: Running JUnit Tests in parallel works quite well with Mave/Surefire so that's not what I worry about. But to assure cross-platform compatibility I have to run the same classes in different browsers (FF,IE,...) thats the problem at the time

Comment: After 5min of investigation I decided to switch to TestNG thanks

Comment: is there a good way to pass the driver from method to method if you group tests across various classes?

Comment: In that case, you should use some form of dependency injection. If your tests are simple, create a global variable with lazy init. http://blog.pdark.de/2010/03/04/java-tricks-lazy-initialization/

Comment: I thought of a DataProvider in an Abstract TestClass that offers some kind of WebDriverPool and the configuration for various test runs